# Performing methods on multiple cursor in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, cursor, ace-editor

I'm am using Ace editor and i can only perform functions on a single cursor and not multiple cursors
for instance

```
 editor.navigateLineStart();
```

will move the cursor to the beginning of the line if there is one cursor but not if there are multiple cursors

this can be done manually by typing (left-home)
because of the code below which is in the document ace.js, but I don't understand how to set multiSelectAction to "forEach" or if that would even help

```
{name: "gotolinestart",
bindKey: bindKey("Alt-Left|Home", "Command-Left|Home|Ctrl-A"),
exec: function(editor) { editor.navigateLineStart(); },
multiSelectAction: "forEach",
readOnly: true
}
```

there is also a function

```
 forEachSelection(String cmd, String args)
```

http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor
which Executes a command for each selection range.
but I don't know what to enter for args
i think for command the input is "gotolinestart" but i'm not sure about that either
the other functions that i can get to work one cursor but not for multiple cursors include

```
editor.getSelection().selectLeft();
editor.navigateLeft(args.times);
```

any examples of functions working multiple cursors and selections in ace editor would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears there is a bug in the documentation it should say `forEachSelection({exec:function}, arg:any)`

arg can be anything and it is simply passed to cmd.exec

also it works only if there are multiple selections, so you need to do something like

```
if (editor.selection.rangeCount > 1)
    editor.forEachSelection({exec: function() {
        editor.editor.navigateLeft(10);
    }})
} else
    editor.editor.navigateLeft(10);
```

another way would be to use execCommand

```
editor.execCommand({
    exec:function() {
        editor.selection.selectLeft()
    },
    multiSelectAction: "forEach"
})
```